# Fluent Nhibernate problem

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this in my entity:

```
public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<long> Blas { get; set; }
```

and this for my mapping:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Blas).AsSet().Element("Value", m => m.Type<long>());
```

This creates the relevant tables and I add data like this:

```
X.Blas = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<long>();
X.Blas.Add(some_long);
```

This adds values to the object but the values in Blas are never persisted (everything else of X is).

Can anyone see anything wrong?

Thanks.

Christian

Comment: I tried ICollection as well. Still the data is not persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if X is loaded through a session then blas is initialized with a changetracking collection. So dont overwrite it. Try `X.Blas.Clear();` instead of `X.Blas = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<long>();`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a cascade setting.

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Blas).AsSet()
       .Element("Value", m => m.Type<long>())
       .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Also you should just be able to use ICollection and a regular Hashset instead of Iesi. Provided you're using at least version 3 (it might work with 2.1.2 or higher as well)

Comment: Thanks. Unfort. the values in Blas are still not persisted (and Blas def. contains some)!

Comment: Hmm, is the session being flushed, are you by chance rolling back a transaction. Enabling cascading should be all that is required.

Comment: no exception. no rollback. yes i flush the session like this: NHibernateSession.Current.Flush(); NHibernateSession.Current.Clear();

Comment: I have to add that the parent object contains Blas and I add data to the child (the class that inherits). However, I don't think that should make any difference.

Comment: I don't think that lists of elements need cascades, because the are value objects and can't be persisted separately. Cascading is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow proper object oriented encapsulation to avoid problems like this, an example in my post here: [How do I map a collection accessed through a read only property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852619/how-do-i-map-a-collection-accessed-through-a-read-only-property/6106729#6106729)